# Is this the correct conversion form an lme4 Generalised Linear Mixed Model glmer or lmer R script to a formula?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I conducted a randomized block design experiment to measure a traits in a population of plants in a growth chamber.

I have 3 blocks (shelf heigh) each containing 3 subblocks (shelf position), each containing 12 subblocks (tray position), as well as x and y coordinates.

This [website](https://www.muscardinus.be/statistics/nested.html) helped me nest the blocks within each other to prevent erroneous crossover.

I used the following script:

```r
> model <- glmer(trait ~ (1|genotype) + (1|year) + (1|year:x) + 
                         (1|year:y) + (1|year:height) + (1|year:shelf) + 
                         (1|year:shelf:x) + (1|year:shelf:x) + 
                         (1|year:tray), data = df, family = binomial)
```

My attempt at formatting this to standard formula is as follows:

[image: equation]

```r
(symptom_ijk) = μ + (G_i) + (A_j) + (A_j)(X_ij) + (A_j)(Y_ij) + (H_ij) + 
        (A_j)(S_ij) + (A_j)(SX_ij) + (A_j)(SY_ij) + (A_j)(T_ij) + (ε_ijk)
```

- where `symptom_ijk` is the measured symptom score,
- μ is the overall mean,
- `G_i` is the effect from the $i$th line,
- `A_j` is the effect from the $j$th year,
- `A_j X_ij` is the effect of the interaction between the $j$th year and the x coordinate,
- `A_j Y_ij` is the effect of the interaction between the $j$th year and the y coordinate,
- `H_ij` is the effect of the interaction between the $j$th year and the shelf height,
- `A_jS_ij` is the effect of the interaction between the $j$th year and shelf location,
- `A_jSX_ij` is the effect of the interaction between the $j$th year, shelf location, and x coordinate,
- `A_jSY_ij` is the effect of the interaction
  between the jth year, shelf location, and y coordinate,
- `A_jT_ij` is the
  effect of the interaction between the $j$th year and germination tray,
- `ε_ijk` is residual error.

Is this anywhere near correct?